# Suggestions please on overview of process

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have an RFID reader that has embedded wi-fi. It sends data (card data) to a server and the data is displayed using PHP web page.
I want to be able to have this data feed from the reader displyed on an android 2.2 tablet.
The tablet and reader are connected to the same wifi router.
So the process is read tag data, pass to android tablet, tablet application passes data to php page and page updates display.
What would be the best route for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use php page to relay the informaiton back to the phone through JSON. The problem with that is its not only local (unless the webpage can only be accessed on your wifi through a webserver). The task of actually making it receive the information over the wifi would be daunting. You would need to edit the software on the server to allow socket connections from your android phone, and to make it broadcast the information to the phone, then you would have to make the phone decypher whatever data you are sending.